# Cross domain shopping basket

Tags: php, laravel

We want to achieve a functionality where a user goes to a domain A, puts stuff in their basket. When they go to domain B (also owned by us) the contents of the basket he made in A shows up here too.

How do you achieve this in php? How does site b know the identifier of his session on site a?

We looked at coolblue.be and gsmstore.be for inspiration but are clueless :D

Comment: Different domains or different sub-domains?

Comment: You can use the database driver and store sessions in your database. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: Are both domains in the same server? If so you can "share" sessions through db or even file.

Comment: Subdomains are not an option, these are fully qualified domains.

Comment: I do not understand how storing them in a database will help share a session across domains. pardon my ignorance

Comment: Yes both domains are on the same server

Comment: Taking a quick peek at the source code on coolblue.be it looks like they're spawning individual sessions, one on each shop (based on the `PHPSESSID` cookies) - it then looks like these are tied to a unique global id for that session (held in the `Coolblue-Session` cookie... maybe)... and that's probably using database storage to hold the data relevant to that main session. Every site then accesses the same database. This is just guesswork though based on what's visible on the front-end.

Comment: Then it does not need to use DB.

You have to (securely) pass the session id to the other domain.

There you set the session_id() to the received id and session_start()

`session_id($received_id); session_start(); echo $_SESSION['somevar'];`

Comment: Another way would be using an iframe for the cart. It could be in either domain or even a 3rd domain where all payments would go through.
When you update quantities, choose products etc you send a post to the cart/payment website no matter what domain you are 'physycally' on...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create system which does this:

   - 1.When a user logs in on page A you need to set the session id for him and redirect him to B with this session id.
   - 1.1.Session data needs to be stored in database(sessions can be stored in cookie or database, you will need to set saving in a database).
   - 2.When a user is redirected to B this page gives him another session id.
   - 2.1.you need a table in database for page B with sessions_id from pages A and B
   - 2.2.user is then redirected to page A.
   - 3.The user clicks trough page A and add products to basket
   - 4.After some time user come to page B.
   - 4.1.On first visit app checks if user is checked if he have session id from page a from database table for sessions_id from pages A and B.
   - 4.2.If the user haven't visit page A nothing happend, but if user have session from page A, app gets basked data from page A database for sessions and saves to user session in page B. On page B. In both cases in session is set  status that user is checked becase we don't want check on ever pageview
   - 5.DONE!
2. Addition.

   - 1.Records in database table for sessions_id from pages A and B older than few hours can be deleted.
   - 2.The same thing for page A need to be done for page B in same way.